# Can't get HTML page to display

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, css, html

I have created an html page to display in the Page Viewer Webpart in SP which contains a bit of jQuery.  For whatever reason, it will not render in an IE Browser - it just shows a blank white page if I access it directly from the library it is hosted in (however, if I go to edit said HTML page all components display in SP Designer).  I also tested the coding in a jFiddle, and it works fine in that as well.  The codes are below (CSS, HTML, & jQuery) without specific links for security reasons.

Thanks for any suggestions; I'm sure it's some small detail I am overlooking.

CSS stylesheet

```
/* SLIDER CSS */

.slider {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 419px; 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image:url(/img/back.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background:#fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slider li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 20; 
}

/* PAGE STYLES */

.body {
  font-family: arial;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: dark gray;
  text-align:left;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) { 

// settings
var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

function slides(){
  return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
$interval = setInterval(
function(){
  var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

  slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
  slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

  if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

  slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
  slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
}
, $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
);

});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slider.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<ul class="slider">
<li> BLAH BLAH WORDS <img src="/img/courselvls_graph.png" align="right"/> </li>
<li> Deediii daaa dummm </li>
</ul>
```

All the files are hosted in the site assets doc library on the site.

Thanks for any suggestions; I'm sure it's some small detail I am overlooking.

Comment: I would suggest you re-organize your post and re-phrase your question, as this is a bit messy.

Comment: it's better! I think firebug and fiddler are your friends. you are probably having some 404s due to wrong paths, which would expain the blank page. if there is a script error, firebug or IE dev toolbar will tell you exactly where it is.

Comment: Ahh, I see.. I'll try playing with the links.  I'm not entirely sure if that's the reason - as there is no 404 error, just a blank page.  And the images and things still render in Designer, which is why I'm scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to generate same scenario, With following piece of code change I can see the text now

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="slider">
<li> BLAH BLAH WORDS <img src="/img/courselvls_graph.png" align="right"/> </li>
<li> Deediii daaa dummm </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Issue is there in your script reference, by changing it started working..
hope this hint will help!